# Grails project on file change restarts tomcat flushes out session data

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, grails, grails-plugin, tomcat9

Grails project with embedded tomcat on intellij ide : on file change tomcat is restarted but session persistent is not working. User is forced to re-login everytime a change is made in any file

Even tried adding to application.yml
  `servlet: session: persistent: true`

On file change in intellij user should not be forced to re-login